# Find a homomorphism $f$ such that $\ker f = N$, a normal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

> Suppose $G$ is a group, $A\subset G$ a finite subset of order $n$.
>
> Let $H = \{g\in G: \forall_{a\in A}:gag^{-1}\in A\}$ and $N=\{g\in G:\forall_{a\in A}:ga=ag\}$.
>
> Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$. Then, find a homomorphism $f:H\to S_n$ such that $\ker f=N$.

---

I verified myself that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that $N\triangleleft H$. As it is a lot of writing out definitions and using tricks, I'll only show what I used to show that $N$ is normal. This was also the hardest step for me in the first part.

**N is normal:**

Suppose $n\in N$. We have $h^{-1}ah\in A$ for all $a\in A, h\in H$. We'll call $h^{-1}ah=a'$.

Now, as $n\in N$ we have that: $$na'n^{-1}=a' \iff hna'n^{-1}h^{-1}=ha'h^{-1}$$$$=hnh^{-1}ahn^{-1}h^{-1}=hnh^{-1}a(hnh^{-1})^{-1}=hh^{-1}ahh^{-1}=a$$

So $hnh^{-1}\in N$ so that $N$ is normal in $H$.

**For the homomorphism:**

First, we define $\phi_h:A\to A$ by $a\mapsto hah^{-1}$.

This is a bijection: suppose $hah^{-1}=hbh^{-1}$ for $a,b\in A.$ Multiplying with $h$ on the right, and $h^{-1}$ on the left on both sides gives us $a=b$ , so $\phi_h$ is injective $\iff$ surjective, as $\#A=\#A$.

For our homomorphism, we define $f:H\to S_n$ by $h\mapsto\phi_h$. If $f(h)=\operatorname{id}$, then $\phi_h(a)=a$ for all $A$, and since $\phi_h(a)=hah^{-1}(=a)$, we have that this exactly gives us that $h\in N$. So $\ker f=N$.

$f$ is a homomorphism: $f(hp) = \phi_{hp}(a)=(hp)a(hp)^{-1}=hpap^{-1}h^{-1}=h\phi_p(a)h^{-1}=\phi_h\circ \phi_p(a)$

---

I wasn't too sure about the homomorphism, as I use the mappings $\phi_h$ on $A$, which aren't necessarily 'numbers' as in $S_3$. It feels as if I have some kind of isomorphism (not $f$ itself, but a group isomorphic to $S_3$), maybe something along the lines of $f:H\to S(A)$ instead of $f:H\to S_n$? But as $\#A=n$ we have $S(A)\cong S_n$?

Comment: In your question you wrote $S_3$, but did you intend to write $S_n$? If so, then your idea for defining $f$ is fine. You can also define $f : H \to S_n$ directly by choosing an enumeration $A = \{a_i \mid i=1,...,n\}$ and then defining $f$ by the formula $$ ha_ih^{-1}=a_{f(h)(i)} $$

Comment: Thank you, I indeed meant $S_n$. Is it true that in my homomorphism, I used $S(A)$ instead of $S_n$?

Comment: Yes, that's right, $f : H \to S(A)$ instead of $f  : H \to S_n$.